# What is the security standard for a small business?

Tags: security

This maybe a very newbie question, but exactly what do I need so that I can say my network is considered "secure"?

To be more specific, if I have a website that deals with login/signup and lots of money transactions, what do I need to protect it?

So far I know I need EV SSL certificate, login system protections like brute force login protection, hashing the password, key stretching. Is there anything I missed?

Besides, is firewall really necessary in my case? I just feel like everything I want to do can be accomplished by the server itself, so is there really a need to get a software/hardware firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be completely blunt, you should probably hire a security professional to assess and make recommendations about your site. Alternatively, a part or full-time network administrator with security experience/certifications might be a good hire.

I recommend the "don't do-it-yourself" approach not because I want to increase work for my peers, or that I don't believe you are a fully competent individual. Rather, I recommend it because security is really, really hard to get right, and any site that handles money is an ideal target for any attacker out there. From a professional perspective, you would be best served by getting an expert to secure your network, perhaps on an ongoing basis; this is a situation that security professionals are very used to, and very well equipped to handle. From a legal perspective, getting an expert opinion on such a sensitive matter is essential due diligence, and trying to do it entirely on your own opens you to significant liability if your system gets breached and attackers are able to carry off your customer's data. Which, as your business grows and you gain more visibility online, only more and more likely to happen without ongoing, professional help.